# Java - Adding data from to a JTable from an AbstractTableModel using LinkedLists

Tags: java, user-interface, linked-list, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a GUI in which has a container for a JTable called 'listTable'. I want to populate the JTable with data stored in a linked list, using the AbstractTableModel.

Basically, I have a LinkedList stored in Processing.java. It contains all the data retrieved from a text file. I created an AbstractTableModel to tell the JTable how to be populated. What I want to do now is to populate the JTable in GUI_g with "the contents of the linkedlist".

Anyone can tell me how to do this?

Here is the code:

GUI_g:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class GUI_g extends JFrame {

    public void buildGui() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hotel TV Scheduler");

                JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));

                JPanel chPanel = new JPanel();
                chPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

                JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
                listPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,1,0));

                JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
        infoPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3, 1, 0));


                JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));

                JPanel chlblPanel = new JPanel();
                chlblPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

                JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
                tablePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

                JPanel rmvbtnPanel = new JPanel();
                rmvbtnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

                JPanel centrePanel = new JPanel();
                centrePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));


             //   mainPanel.add(chPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
            //    mainPanel.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
                mainPanel.add(centrePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


                JTable chOneTable = new JTable();
                JTable chTwoTable = new JTable();

                JTable listTable = new JTable(new ProgramTableMode());

                JLabel ch1Label = new JLabel("Channel 1");
                JLabel ch2Label = new JLabel("Channel 2");
                JLabel listLabel = new JLabel("List");

                JButton rmvChOneButton = new JButton("Remove Channel");
                JButton rmvChTwoButton = new JButton("Remove Channel");

                chlblPanel.add(ch1Label);
                chlblPanel.add(ch2Label);

                tablePanel.add(chOneTable);
                tablePanel.add(chTwoTable);

                rmvbtnPanel.add(rmvChOneButton);
                rmvbtnPanel.add(rmvChTwoButton);            

                chPanel.add(chlblPanel);
                chPanel.add(tablePanel);
                chPanel.add(rmvbtnPanel);

                listPanel.add(listLabel);
                listPanel.add(listTable);                

                JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title");
                JLabel genreLabel = new JLabel("Genre");
                JLabel durationLabel = new JLabel("Duration");
                JLabel actorLabel = new JLabel("Actor");
                JLabel directorLabel = new JLabel("Director");
                JLabel rentableLabel = new JLabel("Rentable");
                JLabel synLabel = new JLabel("Synopsis");

                JTextField txtTitle = new JTextField();          
                JTextField txtGenre = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtDuration = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtActor = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtDirector = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtSynopsis = new JTextField();

                JCheckBox rentCB = new JCheckBox();

                JButton btnAddProg = new JButton("Add Program");

                JList channelList = new JList();
                JList timeList = new JList();

                infoPanel.add(titleLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtTitle);
                infoPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
                infoPanel.add(genreLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtGenre);
                infoPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
                infoPanel.add(durationLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtDuration);
                infoPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
                infoPanel.add(actorLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtActor);
                infoPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
                infoPanel.add(directorLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtDirector);
                infoPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
                infoPanel.add(rentableLabel);
                infoPanel.add(rentCB);
                infoPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
                infoPanel.add(synLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtSynopsis);
                infoPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
                infoPanel.add(btnAddProg);
                infoPanel.add(channelList);
                infoPanel.add(timeList);

                centrePanel.add(chPanel);
                centrePanel.add(infoPanel);
                centrePanel.add(listPanel);

                frame.add(mainPanel);
                frame.setVisible(true);


    }


}
```

ProgramTableModel:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class ProgramTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

    protected String[] columnNames = {"Type","Title","Length"};

    private List<Program> data;


    public ProgramTableModel (List<Program> data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

     public String getColumnName(int column) {
         return columnNames[column];
     }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {

            switch (column){
            case 0: return data.get(row).getCategory();
            case 1: return data.get(row).getTitle();
            case 2: return data.get(row).getDuration();
            default: return "N/A";
            }

    }
}
```

Processing:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Processing
{
    List<Program> schedule = new LinkedList<Program>();

    public void readAllData() {

        try{
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String tempString = null;





            while ((tempString = br.readLine()) != null)   {


                String[] row = tempString.split("-");

                if(row[0].compareTo("COMEDY") == 0) {

                    Comedy comedy = new Comedy(row[0], row[1], Integer.parseInt(row[2]), row[3], row[4], Boolean.parseBoolean(row[5]));
                    schedule.add(comedy);

                } 

                else if(row[0].compareTo("DRAMA") == 0) {

                    Drama drama = new Drama(row[0], row[1], Integer.parseInt(row[2]), row[3], row[4], Boolean.parseBoolean(row[5]));
                    schedule.add(drama);

                }

                else if(row[0].compareTo("MUSIC") == 0) {

                    MusicVideo music = new MusicVideo(row[0], row[1], Integer.parseInt(row[2]));
                    schedule.add(music);

                }

                else if(row[0].compareTo("HOTEL") == 0) {

                    HotelInfo hotel = new HotelInfo(row[0], row[1], Integer.parseInt(row[2]));
                    schedule.add(hotel);

                }

            }
            in.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void getAll()
    {
        for (Program p: schedule)
        {
            System.out.println(p.getTitle() + p.getDuration() + p.getCategory() + p);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly where your stuck? Your current question is a bit on the broad side and almost would require folks to write a tutorial for you.

Comment: Basically, I have a LinkedList stored in Processing.java. It contains all the data retrieved from a text file. I created an AbstractTableModel to tell the JTable how to be populated. What I want to do now is to populate the JTable in GUI_g with "the contents of the linkedlist". I will update the main question.

Comment: *Again*, how have you tried to add it to your model? Where is your current attempt failing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reset methos to your `ProgramTableModel` that resets the internal list:

```
public reset (List<Program> data){ 
    this.data = data; 
}
```

then just call `reset()` on the model object that is associated with `listTable`.  This means, you need to store and expose that object from the GUI

Note: you can manipulate your model's list any way you like: add, remove, replace elements, just add the appropriate methods that would enable the desired behavior

Comment: Isn't that the same as what `public ProgramTableModel (List<Program> data){
  this.data = data;
 }`

Is doing ?

Comment: The problem is not exactly in ProgramTableModel but in the GUI.. How do I call it? As in how do I call ProgramTableModel ?

Comment: It is not the same: the one you just listed in the comment is a constructor -- you can only construct an object once.  You can certainly replace the model with a new one if you want, but then you need to expose the JTable, instead of the model.  How to call the method on the model: you need to decide what is the best place to store: if you have access to the GUI_g object, you can use that, otherwise, store the model in a class that both places (GUI and model populator) have access to (more precisely, to the same object).  You can create this common object in say, main and pass it to the others